# Get Enum Name from Value?

Tags: enums, d

I just stumbled on [this topic](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/learn/Converting_from_string_to_enum_by_name_36171.html) while looking for an answer to this question.

Essentially, what I'm asking is the opposite of what's done in that thread. Instead of getting an enum's value by it's name, I'd like to get it's name by it's value. How is this done?

Comment: Enums can be set equal to each other: `enum {white, gray = 1, grey =1, black};`.  They can be built from named enums: enum {user = 4, group = 2; over = 1;}`  These can be manipulated: `enum all = user | group | other;` How would you convert 7 to `"all"` here>

Comment: @EricJablow I guess not... :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it the exact same why, but as Eric points out, it isn't perfect:

```
import std.conv;
import std.stdio;

enum LogLevel { ALL, INFO, WARNING }
enum Color {white, gray = 1, grey =1, black}

void main()
{
     enum l = to!LogLevel(1);
     assert(l == LogLevel.INFO);
     writeln(to!string(l));

     enum c = to!Color(1);
     writeln(to!string(c));
}
```

---

```
INFO
gray
```

Comment: It's very very very great answer. No need to a lot of cases in a switch. No need to the X macro. And no risk to forget to update enum value in a case in the function and return wrong name.